# KeyError at /report_save django

Tags: python, django, forms, number-formatting

I have an issue when trying to save data to model

I have a code that seperate number by comma. If I type number < 1000, I can save data and type of the field is int. If the number >=1000, I cannot save data to model and the error appears

the error
[image]

[image]
This is my code
in my views:

```
form=AddReportForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    so_tien=form.cleaned_data["so_tien"]
    dien_thoai=form.cleaned_data["dien_thoai"]
    daily_report=report(so_tien=so_tien,dien_thoai=dien_thoai)
    daily_report.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('chi_tiet_hop_dong', kwargs={'so_hd': so_hd}))
```

my js code to seperate number in my template:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function numberWithCommas(){
      var input = document.getElementById('{{ form.so_tien.id_for_label}}');
      input.value = parseInt(input.value).toLocaleString()
}
</script>
```

my template:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Số tiền</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">{{ form.so_tien }}</div>
</div>
```

my form:

```
so_tien=forms.IntegerField(label="Số tiền",widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", 'onfocusout': 'numberWithCommas()',}),required=False)

dien_thoai=forms.CharField(label="Điện thoại",max_length=12, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}))
```

Please help me solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the comma when the number is greatest than 1000.

Option 1: Delete the comma before save the form

```
if form.is_valid():
    so_tien=form.cleaned_data["so_tien"].replace(",","")
    dien_thoai=form.cleaned_data["dien_thoai"]
    daily_report=report(so_tien=so_tien,dien_thoai=dien_thoai)
    daily_report.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('chi_tiet_hop_dong', kwargs={'so_hd': so_hd}))
```

Option 2: Change the type of the field "so_tien" in your model to CharField and makemigrations again.

Option 3: Use an input type number (with step="1" for integers) in your form.

```
so_tien=forms.IntegerField(label="Số tiền",widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"type":"number", "step":"1", "class":"form-control", 'onfocusout': 'numberWithCommas()',}),required=False)
```

EDIT: Option 3 may not work because "numberWithCommas()" overrides the input value.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I try 3 opitions, but the error is still. I think form.cleaned_data get number in field "so_tien", but numberWithCommas() converts number to text with comma, so form.clean_data cannot get the number. If number <1000, it doesnt has comma, so form.cleaned_data get exactly number

Comment: Try this -->    so_tien=int(form.cleaned_data["so_tien"].replace(",","").replace(".",""))